# I am unable to upload big file with NGINX, NGINX max upload has no effect

Tags: django, nginx, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I'm learning Django, Docker and Nginx. For this, I am using nginx proxy but it is throwing 413 Request Entity Too Large when uploading images but the image size is not significant.

I added client_max_body_size 1024M; in htttp, server and location in nginx.conf and default.conf but it did not solve my problem
Do I need to do any thing to uwsgi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Max Upload Size on django settings.  You can set the `DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE` and `FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE` settings in your settings

And update the nginx.conf

```
client_body_buffer_size 1024M;
client_header_buffer_size 1024M;
large_client_header_buffers 4 1024M;
```